# How can I format data like this?

Tags: python, bigdata, apache-spark

**Note**: This question is related to Spark using Python (Python) and not just ordinary Python. It uses RDD objects and not just simple Python lists.

So, I have a list of actors along with their casted movies. I want to create key value pairs, where key is the actor and values are the movies in which he worked. The data format is such that you have an actor tab separated with the movie in which he worked. If he worked in more movies, for example, in case of *Abalov Eduard*, the extra movies are listed in lines below it. I've already extracted the data from the file in the format shown below. However, I want the actor name to appear against all the movies he worked, so that I can just call a map function to create key value pairs. So for example, for Abalov Eduard, I want his name to appear against all his movies. For example, instead of

```
[u'', u'', u'', u'Severnaya rapsodiya (1974)']
```

I want

```
[u'Abalov, Eduard', u'Severnaya rapsodiya (1974)']
```

How can I do that? Would I need to use `mappartitions`? Or is there an easier way to achieve that?

```
[
[u'Abalos, Rogelio', u'', u'Sa pagitan ng dalawang mata (1963)  <22>'], 
[u''], 
[u'Abalos, Ronald A.', u'Alchemy (2013)  [Group Member]  <21>'], 
[u''], 
[u'Abalos, Tarzan', u'', u'Bagong buwan (2001)  [MILF Group]  <82>'], 
[u''], 
[u'Abalov, Eduard', u'', u'Chistye prudy (1965)  (as E. Abalov)'], 
[u'', u'', u'', u'Novye priklyucheniya neulovimykh (1968)  (as E. Abalov)'], 
[u'', u'', u'', u'Severnaya rapsodiya (1974)'], 
[u'', u'', u'', u'Stoyanka poyezda - 2 minuty (1972) (TV)'], 
[u'', u'', u'', u'Stryapukha (1965)  (as E. Abalov)'], 
[u'', u'', u'', u'"12 stulev" (1977)  (as E. Abalov)'], 
[u''], 
[u'Abalyan, I.', u'', u'Ne delayte biskvity v plokhom nastroenii (2003)']
]
```

Comment: Just keep an extra variable with the name of the last actor seen. If a new list doesn't have an actor, add it. You can update your existing list or do it as you build your dict.

Comment: I am using Pyspark for spark, not ordinary python. I am working on RDD objects, not ordinary lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
actordata = [[u'.....' ]]
clean_data = [] 
last_actor = None
for item in actordata: 
   if len(item) < 1: # ignore the [u''] 
      continue
   last_actor = item[0] if item[0] != u'' else last_actor
   clean_data.append([last_actor, item[-1]] )
```

Comment: In simple python this would work, but I'm using Spark (Pyspark).